# where can i find papers/optimization concepts about email server/email storage?

Tags: data-storage, mail-server

I would like to know about the optimization techniques in email server/storage. Where do i get this information? I understand that gmail and outlook are not open source. But the manner in which they store emails at the server side is a problem that could've been dealt with by researchers or programmers already. Have such things been published somewhere? I am not concerned about how email is sent/received/MTA etc. Just concerned abt the way its stored. Wikipedia talks only about transfer protocols but nothing related to storage. Plz point me to some articles.

Thx,
Venu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E-mail can be stored in databases quite efficiently. Alternatively you can store it in the file system (i.e. on the disk) or in the virtual file system which supports storing of metadata. We recently published an [article on storing data in different storages](https://www.eldos.com/news/6938.php).

Outlook uses custom storage, similar to virtual file system.

Comment: Hey... thx... however your article does not talk about exact techniques. For e.g. how threaded messages are stored and how their contexts are interpreted etc. Again i am concerned exactly about the data structure used to store various fields and the linkage among them.

Comment: The things you are asking about are task- and implementation-specific techniques which you have to design yourself. Threaded messages are not stored as threaded - each message has a In-response-to field, and the ID of the referenced message is taken from that field and stored in metadata as well as the ID of the message itself. Then you get a classic hierarchical structure in the DB. This is if you use the DB. If you use regular or virtual file system, approaches will be different. This is where you choose what and how to do.